# redirect blocked ip to different url in nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

In my `Nginx` config I have

```
location / {
allow 198.168.0.1;
deny all;
}
```

Now, I want to redirect all other IPs except the allowed one to `google.com`, how do I do that ?

I have tried something like

```
location / {
allow 198.168.0.1;
deny all;
rewrite ^ http://google.com/;
}
```

but this redirects directly to `google.com` for all IP. I want only `198.168.0.1` to access the page, others would be redirected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`error_page`](http://nginx.org/r/error_page) directive for this.

```
location / {
    allow 198.168.0.1;
    deny all;
    error_page 403 http://www.google.com/;
}
```

Since the `deny all` will serve a 403 error, we override the 403 handling by sending a redirect to `http://www.google.com/`.